# PHP number format error

Tags: php

I wanted to shorten my numbers by a few , so maximum numbers will be 5.

for example instead of

2.2333333333

it will show

2.23333

I used this code:

```
    echo "<tr><td>".$results['playerName']."</td><td>".$results['Runecraftlvl']."</td><td>".$results['Runecraftxp']."</td><td>".$results['kills']."</td><td>".$results['deaths']."</td><td>".$results['targkills']."</td><td>". $number_format("$Kdr",5)."</td></tr>";
```

On the last variable

```
<td>". $number_format("$Kdr",5)."</td>
```

Works fine, but if user got 0 Kdr or something, it will print this error:

Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Why does it do that? How can it be fixed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add the following line to the top of your file

```
$Kdr = '';
```

does it work properly then?

and indeed $number_format() should be number_format()

Comment: I have this already:

  if ($results["kills"] != 0) {
  $Kdr = $results["kills"] / $results["deaths"];
  }

Comment: aye, so if [kills] is NOT 0, then $Kdr contains something, otherwise it's empty.

Answer (score 5):

```
$number_format
```

should be

```
number_format
```